# Trying to loop over multiple files in a directory. How to change a variable object?

Tags: python, loops

I'm trying to create a loop to parse gff3 files into a table with transcript IDs to gene name. So far I have a script that works on a single gff3 file, but I want to be able to create a loop to quickly iterate over multiple gff3 files in a directory.

Here's the script:

```
import pandas as pd
from dammit.fileio.gff3 import GFF3Parser

gff_file="{BAT}.dammit.gff3"
annotations = GFF3Parser(filename=gff_file).read()
names = annotations.sort_values(by=['seqid', 'score'], ascending=True).query('score < 1e-05').drop_duplicates(subset='seqid')[['seqid', 'Name']]
new_file = names.dropna(axis=0,how='all')
new_file.to_csv("{BAT}_gene_name_ids.csv")
```

I want to create a loop that changes `{BAT}` to the filename of the
species for which I have a dammit annotation file for, then produce a
`{BAT] _gene name_ids.csv` for each file I loop through.

How can I change this into an executable loop?

Comment: Do you not know how to write a loop in Python in general, or what has been the difficulty?

Comment: In general, I am not strong with writing python loops. I know how to call a variable file in bash/python, but am struggling to do so in python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to list all gff3 files in the targeted directory first and then iterate through that list.

```
import os  # You need this module to list all files in a directory
import pandas as pd
from dammit.fileio.gff3 import GFF3Parser

targeted_directory = 'Full path to the directory including all gff3 files.'  # change here

all_files = os.listdir(targeted_directory)  # list file names

for gff_file in all_files:
    gff_file = os.path.join(all_files, gff_file)  # get full path to the file name
    annotations = GFF3Parser(filename=gff_file).read()
    names = annotations.sort_values(by=['seqid', 'score'],    ascending=True).query('score < 1e-05').drop_duplicates(subset='seqid')   [['seqid', 'Name']]
    new_file = names.dropna(axis=0,how='all')
    new_file.to_csv("{BAT}_gene_name_ids.csv")
```

If you want to filter files based on a pattern, use `glob` module:

```
import globe
filtered_files = glob.glob(pattern)
```

Check [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob) for more details about `globe`.

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked, but I had to omit the "os.path.join" line.

Comment: Your welcome. If the script is running from another directory, that line will be needed.